# relations with 2 rows and user id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So what I'm trying to do is this, basically I have a table called games which has

`creator_id`
and
`guest_id`

now what i want to do is when i want to list all games i want to join two tables and get for example if `creator_id` is John and `guest_id` is Mary

i want to list all the "games" with their names

> ID: 322   |     Creator Name: John   |     Guest Name: Mary

and so on, this is what i got so far:

Controller:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }

    public function listGames()
    {
        $games = Game::get();
        return view('admin.games.list', compact('games'));
    }
}
```

View:

```
@extends('admin.content')

@section('title', 'List games')

@section('content')

<table class="table table-hover">

@foreach($games as $game)

// now i want to list that here

@endforeach
</table>

@endsection
```

Later on I added this to games model

```
public function creator() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'creator_id');
}

public function guest() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'guest_id');
}
```

this to controller

```
public function index() {
    $games = Game::with('creator', 'guest')->get();
    return view('admin.games.list', compact('games'));
}
```

and looped like this

```
@foreach($games as $game)
    Creator: {{ $game->creator->name }}
    Guest: {{ $game->guest->name }}
@endforeach
```

but then this occured

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.creator_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from users where users.creator_id in (14, 15, 16) and users.deleted_at is null), I dont know why but i dont have creator_id and guest_id in users table, its in games table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the relation of the Game model to:

```
public function creator() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id');
}

public function guest() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'guest_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the child and the parent model. The games don't *have* users - they `belongTo()` them, since the games table contain the ids of the parents.

And for the inverse, unless each user can only create or play one game, you should use `hasMany()` rather than `hasOne()`.